# Multi-pass shading using render-to-texture

Tags: c++, glsl, render-to-texture, openscenegraph, multipass

I'm trying to implement a multi-pass rendering method using OpenSceneGraph.  However, I'm not entirely certain my problem is theoretical or due to a lack of applied knowledge of OSG.  Thus far, I've successfully implemented multi-pass shading by rendering to a texture using an orthogonal projection, but I cannot seem to make a perspective projection work.

It may be that I don't quite understand how to implement multi-pass shading.  Of course, I have to pre-render the entire scene with the multi-pass shaders to a texture, then use the texture in the final render.  However, I'm not talking about creating a separate texture for each object in the scene, but effectively capturing a screenshot of the entire prerendered scene.  Then, from that texture alone, applying the rendered effects to the individual geometries.

I assume this means I would have to do an extra conversion of the vertex coordinates for each geometry in the vertex shader.  That is, after computing:

```
gl_Position = ModelViewProjectionMatrix * Vertex;
```

I would need to go a step further and calculate the vertex's screen coordinates in order to map the vertices correctly (again, given that the texture consists of an entire screen shot of the scene).

If I am correct, then I must be able to pre-render the scene in a perspective view identical to the view used in the final render, rather than an orthogonal view.  This is where I have troubles.  I can make an orthogonal view do what I want, but not the perspective view.

Am I correct in my approach?  The only other approach I can imagine is to render everything to a screen-filling quad (in effect, the same thing as converting to screen coordinates), but that doesn't alleviate the need to use a perspective projection in the pre-render stage.

Thoughts?  Links??

edit:  I should also point out that in my successful attempts, I used a fragment shader only.  The perspective projection worked, but, of course, the screen aligned quad I was using was offset rather than centered.  I added a pass-through vertex shader and everything went blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, my approach was correct.  It's especially nice as it avoids having to add another camera to my scene graph to render the final output - I can simply use the main camera.  Unfortunately, it means that all of my output textures are rendered at the screen resolution, rather than a resolution appropriate to the size of the object.  That is, if my screen is 1024 x 1024, then so is the output texture, one for each pre-render camera in the graph.  Not exactly efficient, but it'll do for now.